# The offset of each field and the size of the following structure declarations

Tags: c

A. `struct P1 {short i; int c; int *j; short *d;};`

D. `struct P4 {char w[16]; int *c[2]};`

E. `struct P5 {struct P4 a[2]; struct P1 t};`

The answer said the total size of P1 is 16 bytes. But I think the short takes 4 (insert 2 bytes to satisfy alignment requirement), int takes 4, two pointers *j and *d each takes 8. So the total size should be 4 + 4 + 8 + 8 = 24. Do I get it wrong? Besides, for the E. P5,  the offset of t is 24. I don't know how it comes. a[2] is an array with two elements. Each element is a P4 structure. Since the size of P4 is 32, shouldn't a[2] take 64 bytes?

Comment: What architecture are you working on? `x86` or `x86-64`?

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio x86-64

Comment: This is impossible to answer completely without knowing what architecture or other details the answer key assumes. But there's no possible way on any compliant implementation that `offsetof(struct P5, t) == 24`.

Comment: If the answer says that the total size of P1 is 16 bytes, then it is probably assuming that the pointers and `int` are four bytes each.  Such an answer also makes some other assumptions about padding, including that there is no *trailing* padding.  The text must present the details informing the structure layouts it is asking you about, or if it doesn't then you need a better text.  The C language itself requires only that the members appear in the same order they are declared, they do not overlap, and there is no padding before the first.

Comment: The book was obvious written with 32 bit architectures in mind, that have 32 bit addresses. You can't make any such assumptions, why you need to edit the question and specify the exact system used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The offset of each field and the size of the following structure declarations

There are many issues of  padding, alignment and integer sizes that affect the result.  Best to use standard code to report the offset values and sizes.

> So the total size should be 4 + 4 + 8 + 8 = 24. Do I get it wrong?

Reasonable calculation, yet not definitive.  Size depends on alignment, padding of the compiler and platform.  Even for a known architecture, the result may vary depending on the compiler and its options.

> Since the size of P4 is 32, shouldn't a[2] take 64 bytes?

Like the prior question, many considerations are in play.

---

To find the offset of a member in a `struct`, use `offsetof()`

To find the size of a `struct`, use `sizeof()`.

To print these values, use the correct matching print specifier: `"%zu"`

Use proper syntax.  Review use of `;` in `P4` and `P5`.

---

```
struct P1 {
  short i;
  int c;
  int *j;
  short *d;
};

struct P4 {
  char w[16];
  int *c[2];
};

struct P5 {
  struct P4 a[2];
  struct P1 t;
};

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("PI i:%zu\n", offsetof(struct P1, i));
  printf("PI c:%zu\n", offsetof(struct P1, c));
  printf("PI j:%zu\n", offsetof(struct P1, j));
  printf("PI d:%zu\n", offsetof(struct P1, d));
  printf("PI size:%zu\n\n", sizeof(struct P1));

  printf("P4 w:%zu\n", offsetof(struct P4, w));
  printf("P4 c:%zu\n", offsetof(struct P4, c));
  printf("P4 size:%zu\n\n", sizeof(struct P4));

  printf("P5 a:%zu\n", offsetof(struct P5, a));
  printf("P5 t:%zu\n", offsetof(struct P5, t));
  printf("P5 size:%zu\n\n", sizeof(struct P5));
}
```

Output: Your output may vary.

```
PI i:0
PI c:4
PI j:8
PI d:12
PI size:16

P4 w:0
P4 c:16
P4 size:24

P5 a:0
P5 t:48
P5 size:64
```

Comment: @VitaZ We could calculate _minimum_ size: P1, P4, P5: 4,18, 40.  (Think 32-bit char, short, int, *) or a not-so esoteric small processor P1, P4, P5: 8, 20, 48.  (Think 8-bit char, 16-bit short/int, *) of an embedded processor.  Many possibilities.  Deeper insight: That is the origin of C - to port to all sorts of platforms.   "The answer said the total size of P1 is 16 bytes" is leading you into questionable coding practice as 16 is a reasonable, yet not certain result - even for x86-64. [Think outside the box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking_outside_the_box).

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to find out a solution: write code and run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct P1 {
        short i;
        int c;
        int* j;
        short* d;
} P1_t;

typedef struct P2 {
        char w[16];
        int* c[2];
} P4_t;

typedef struct P5 {
        P4_t a[2];
        P1_t t;
} P5_t;

int main() {
        P1_t a;
        P4_t b;
        P5_t c;
        printf("%d %d %d\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(b), sizeof(c));
        return 0;
}
```

However, since primitive types and pointer like `int` and `short*` are not linked to a specific size, the results can vary depending on the platform. I ran it on Windows Subsystem for Linux and my output was:
`$ 24 32 88`

Comment: I run the code and it shows the answer of the book is wrong. That's really a good way to test. Thank you!

Comment: @VitaZ A book that ask you this question with these answers should be throw away... just to record it, what is your book ?

Comment: @Stargateur CSAPP (Computer systems : a programmer's perspective). I think they changed the question in the new edition but didn't update the answer since I found the answer matched the questions in the old edition